# Satellite 5.8 - cdn-sync not syncing

Tags: redhat, satellite

I've been working with a RedHat Satellite that is used for internal
Linux systems. It's set up to sync a subset of the channels available
from RedHat, and the sync has been done using `satellite-sync` in a
cron job.

The satellite was recently upgraded from 5.7 to 5.8. This upgrade
includes replacing the `satellite-sync` with the new
`cdn-sync`. According to RedHat documentation, it should be a drop-in
replacement, and they recommend running it through a cron job that
randomizes run time to be between 1 am and 3 am, like this:

```
0 1 * * * perl -le 'sleep rand 9000' && cdn-sync --email >/dev/null 2>1
```

However, we have found that when we do that, *nothing* gets
downloaded. There is no error message; all we get is an email that
says the command took 00:00 minutes:seconds to run. We've also tried
directing output to a log file instead of to /dev/null, but we get no
other information and no error message. Still, nothing gets synced.

How can we get `cdn-sync` to actually *sync* the packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first time you run `cdn-sync` after upgrading, you need to
specify the channel that you want to keep synced. So we had to manually
run

```
cdn-sync-c rhel-x86_64-server-6 -c rhel-x86_64-server-optional-6 [...other channels] --email
```

When we had run it this way manually once, the cron job started
working.